# How come I cannot strip_tags with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, strip-tags

I trying to return a value to the html ul, ajax has no problem. For example, If ajax return apple, I can echo $html as apple. But if I strip_tags $html, it doesn't echo anythings. But If I put some text between ul and echo with strip_tags, it can echo these text. So what have I done wrong?

```
 $.ajax({   
            url:'member_search.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{ 
            search_text: $(".result_tag").text()            
                        },
            error: function(){
            $('#find_members').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
            },
            success: function(data){
            $("#get_user").text(data);                  
            }
            });
```

```html
<?php

    $html ="<ul id='get_user'></ul>";
    $arrayUL = explode(",", strip_tags($html));
    print_r($arrayUL);//Array ( [0] => )

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can see from your code, your `$html` variable is instantiated with an html tag string already and you are not putting anything else in the variable. After this you run `strip_tags()` on the `$html`. This remove any html tags. The resulting is now an empty string.

Comment: The .ajax will input some text inside the html tag. it work sif I only echo $html, but if I use strip_tags, it remove everything

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong, your code works as expected. Remember that strip_tags Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string.

You should read this:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

This code always will return a empty string, because his tags were strippeds.

```
<?php

$html ="<ul id='get_user'></ul>";
var_dump(strip_tags($html));

?>
```

And this code always will return the info inside the tag.

```
<?php

$html ="<ul id='get_user'>Apple</ul>";
var_dump(strip_tags($html));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. I know if something inside the tag, it will echo out. I don't put anything between the tag because .ajax will put the text between the tag. And then when I use strip_tag, it echo nothing

Comment: And then what is your problem? My answer responded your question?

Comment: @kenny you got some advance?